# Word VBA Alternate Word Highlighting using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, range, highlight

Hi heres the scenario: I need to highlight words in alternating colors of red and green and i have the following code that is already working. Question is, how can this be done without using the Mod or Modulo operator? It should also be using Range. Any suggestions are welcomed! Thanks guys!

Module to call the Function:

```
Sub Test()
'If to call the function
If (altHighlight(ActiveDocument.Range)) = True Then MsgBox "Alternate Highlighting Done!"

End Sub
```

Function for alternate highlighting:

```
Function altHighlight(R As Range) As Boolean
    Dim eachWord As Range
    Dim count As Integer

    For Each eachWord In R.Words
        If count Mod 2 = 0 Then
            eachWord.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed
        Else
            eachWord.HighlightColorIndex = wdGreen
        End If
        count = count + 1
    Next
    altHighlight = True
End Function
```

Comment: Why are you trying to eliminate `Mod`? Is this homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before computers could do division quickly, there were two common ways to alternate things.

The least significant bit of an integer will alternate between 0 and 1 as it is incremented. You can use the bitwise AND operator to single out that bit:

```
Function altHighlight(R As Range) As Boolean
    Dim eachWord As Range
    Dim count As Integer

    For Each eachWord In R.Words
        If count And 1 = 0 Then
            eachWord.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed
        Else
            eachWord.HighlightColorIndex = wdGreen
        End If
        count = count + 1
    Next
    altHighlight = True
End Function
```

Since you're not actually counting the items in your range, you can just make `count` itself toggle between 0 and 1:

```
Function altHighlight(R As Range) As Boolean
    Dim eachWord As Range
    Dim count As Integer

    For Each eachWord In R.Words
        If count = 0 Then
            eachWord.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed
        Else
            eachWord.HighlightColorIndex = wdGreen
        End If
        count = 1 - count
    Next
    altHighlight = True
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Gabe. Thanks for the quick reply. I would much prefer your code than mine lol! Thank you for clearing some of my confusions with alternates. This will come in handy soon. :)

Comment: Oh one last question: is there a better way of doing the alternate color than the ones above using For Each eachWord In R.Words?